# I have created a time picker in a dialog and I get an error in the fragment class

Tags: android

The method is12HourFormat(Activity) is undefined for the type DateFormat in the following line.

```
class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
    implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute, DateFormat.is12HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("00");
        selectTime.setText( selectedHour + ":" + formatter.format(selectedMinute));
        selected_Hour = selectedHour;
        selected_Minute = selectedMinute;
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you at least check the docs ? **`android.text.format.DateFormat` class has no such method** ... also why such question has +1 vote?

Comment: but Its working for 24HourFormat i dont know about 12hourFormat..

Comment: obviously if format is 24 then is not 12 ...